# How to integrate ctool Modal with VBO

Tags: chaos-tool-suite

I have a big problem with Views Bulk Operations and Ctools.

1. I defined a new button in VBO such as: Print and displays it on
   Content View List.
2. Into the Content View List, I check any rows into View List and
   click Print button.
3. When  click Print Button, show Modal (by Ctools) with the selected content.
4. Direct to the selected Content page.

My question is, how can I get the value of the selected rows. In this case, I'am not able to use #submit defined into the Print's action (by VBO) to show Modal.
Please, help me!

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers. Is there any custom written code involved? If so, please share it with us. If you have used any knowledge resources on the web, please link them so users here can have an idea of what you have done.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, above the bug had fixed. But I have a another bug. I defined a new test_form form includes one text field and submit. When I click submit, display modal form including the values input of  the Test Form, then I click submit on Modal Form but the message errors display. I check recent log : "invalid Post form error"

Comment: This site is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum. You should ask new questions by posting a question instead of commenting. Also, if you have solved a problem, it would be good to share how you did that. You can write answers to your own question too. Please refer to the [help center](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help) for more information about how to use this site.